# Facebook Graph API returns 403 Forbidden

Tags: tomcat, facebook-graph-api, http-post

I'm having a problem using graph API. 
My program worked perfectly until two months ago. 
And yesterday I ran my program, and it suddenly fails to call graph API. 
My server uses HttpPost object to make httpPost request. 
When I copy-paste the exact same request URL to the web browser, it receives corrent JSON response,(so I don't think a token or url is the problem) but when it comes to HttpPost, it fails and get HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden response.

I may have changed my server configuration, but I can't remember. Has Graph API changed for last two months? I need help.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to pull the response. Facebook will usually detail the reason in the response.

If you can't pull the response directly be sure to run an HTTP debug utility, like [HTTP Debugger](http://www.httpdebugger.com/)*, to pull the enable you to send real HTTP posts and see the responses.

- A free or open source tool may exist. I have used this one with success, but I'm not advocating it as the only tool.

Comment: Thanks. I solved this problem by using get method instead of post method. Thanks :)

Comment: can you add your solution please?